# Getting IP of incoming input stream in Java

Tags: java, sockets, ip

I have a very simple chat program, you just send a class to the server and it reads it etc. i want the server to be able to return information to the people connected, how do i find the ip of incoming connections?

Comment: Check the `Socket` javadoc.

Comment: You don't need the IP address for this. Sockets are bidirectional.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Socket s = ...
InetSocketAddress isa = (InetSocketAddress) s.getRemoteSocketAddress();
InetAddress addr = isa.getAddress();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `Socket` class there is the method `getInetAddress()` returns the address to which the socket is connected.

you can read more on the java doc : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html